# How can I successfully use a decorator function for my problem?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use the pie "@" syntax for decorators but I can't seem to get this to work for my particular example.

I can achieve my intended result with this..

```
import pandas as pd

def prepare_todays_campaigns(decorated):
  
  campaigns_outgoing = pd.DataFrame({"test":[1,2,3]})

  n_campaigns = len(campaigns_outgoing)

  if n_campaigns > 0:

      print(
          f"{n_campaigns} to process."
      )

      decorated(campaigns_outgoing)
      
def dec_test(campaigns_outgoing):
  for _, row in campaigns_outgoing.iterrows():
    print(row)
    

prepare_todays_campaigns(dec_test)
```

i.e.

[image]

But when I try and use the @ syntactic sugar, I can't seem to get my expected result...

```
def prepare_todays_campaigns(decorated):
  
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    # creatives x campaign
    campaigns_outgoing = pd.DataFrame({"test":[1,2,3]})

    n_campaigns = len(campaigns_outgoing)

    if n_campaigns > 0:

        print(
            f"{n_campaigns} to process."
        )

        decorated(*args, **kwargs)

    
  return wrapper

@prepare_todays_campaigns
def dec_test(campaigns_outgoing):
  for _, row in campaigns_outgoing.iterrows():
    print(row)
    
dec_test()
```

Result:

[image]

Does anyone have any recommendations as to how to solve this?

Comment: What result did you expect, and what did you get? That aside, I don't see any reason to use decorator syntax here. Decorators are typically used to create new functions, or to do something with the function other than simply call it. Your first code is much clearer.

Comment: Have attached expected and observed above. Thanks for clarifying decorator use there. I suppose my desire is more of a curiosity as to why the second approach doesn't work, because following a tutorial I found online, I thought them to be equivalent... https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: The main problem appears to be that `wrapper` itself defines `campaigns_outgoing`, but then never actually passes it as an argument to `decorated`.

Comment: You're right, it has been a long day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the method signature `def dec_test(campaigns_outgoing):`

And when you call the method:

`dec_test()`

You do not pass in the `campaigns_outgoing` argument.